# Clear Used Range Starting With Specific Cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I want to clear the used range of Sheet1, but starting with A8 and down.  I want to leave the data in A7 and up in-tact, but anything below that range, clear out.  I tried this syntax, but it is not going all the way to the end of the workbook ("used range").  And yes, the last cell of the used range is before A65536

```
For LastRow = 2 To Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
  Next LastRow
Range("A" & LastRow).ClearContents
```

How can I clear all cells with data from row A8 to end of used range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close try the below - this way you do not have to specify the "end range".  It will delete everything below row 8

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Rows(8 & ":" & .Rows.Count).Delete
End With
```

Comment: Perfect, I love that I do not have to specify an end cell to search to

Comment: One thing to be aware of:  There is a downside to using `Delete` rather than `ClearContents` - any formula in the first 7 rows that is referring to the later rows will be broken (e.g. if D7 contained `=SUM(D8:D5000)` it will be replaced with `=SUM(#REF!)`).  It doesn't appear to be an issue for the OP, but other users may get caught out by it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code (other than doing nothing in the loop) only builds an address for one cell.  Just build a `Range` like `8:42` or whatever the last row is and clear that:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("8:" & .Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Or version agnostic (which caters for the version of Excel you have, it is Excel-2003 that has 2^16 or 65536  rows)

```
Range([a8], Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).EntireRow.ClearContents
```